# Heroku css not loading after assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Heroku suddenly stopped working and gave me this error:

```
  could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
  Precompiling assets failed.
```

After some research I ran this line:

```
 running RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This worked but now when i push an update to heroku the new css doesn't load. 
This line never used to show before:

```
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
```

If possible can you also explain why the assets:precompile line solved my original problem?

Comment: Read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets this will answer your question reason why you should precompile your assets. But that particular command runs it in production mode using the `exec` command. Also when you say the new CSS won't update what is the error in the console you are getting. Post this

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped me understand it a bit more. There is no error when pushing to heroku it's just that any new css doesn't load.

Comment: At which point when you try to load the page, open firebug or chrome dev tools and go to the console. You should have some sort of output

Comment: Hmm, the chrome devs console just shows some info about fonts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run this commands:

```
 bundle exec rake tmp:clear

 bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production

 bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: All it took was bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production for it to work. Thanks for the help!